# Accessing sent emails

Tags: email

I would like to keep track of emails that I have sent on Civicrm?  Is there a way to do this or do I have to print them to keep a record of sent emails?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a bit more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Do you want to view mass mailings sent through CiviMail? If so Robin's answer should help.

Or do you want to view emails that you have sent to an individual contact in CiviCRM? If so, you can view these in that contact's activity tab.

Or do you want to record emails that you have sent outside of CiviCRM against a contact in CiviCRM?  If so, you can find more details here: [Configuring inbound email processing](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/#configuring-inbound-email-processing)

Answer (score 1):

Emails sent through CiviMail are stored in Mailings > Scheduled and sent mailings, just click the 'report' button next to each mailing.